# Firebase (Google) Cloud Functions - Debounce/Throttle database.onWrite() #AskFirebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

#### Scenario

I have documents stored for each user at path `documents/${documentId}`

#### Goal

I want to parse them and update the index for that document when it changes

#### Code

```
import Functions from 'firebase-functions'

export writeTrigger = Functions
  .database
  .ref('/document/{documentId}')
  .onWrite(
    async event => {
      const data = event.data.val()
      const { documentId } = event.params
      // assume that updateIndex function exists
      updateIndex(documentId, data)
    }
  )
```

#### Problem

This function gets called for every single letter being typed into the document

### TLDR

What is the best way to throttle/debounce firebase cloud functions (database.onWrite) so that it isn't fired on each and every change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function will get invoked *for each and every change at or under the path you specify*.  There's currently no way to prevent this.

Instead of writing each and every change to the database, instead try batching up changes on the client and writing them out in bulk, or saving state periodically.

Alternatively, give the client some other way to indicate that it's time for the function to do work, maybe some field in the document and listen to only that field's changes.  Here's one that just triggers when a field `done` is changed:

```
export writeTrigger = Functions
  .database
  .ref('/document/{documentId}/done')
  .onWrite(...)
```

Just be sure to unset that value so that the client can indicate another set of changes should be processed.

Comment: Hmm, interesting point. I think I'll add a new path that gets written to from the client and gets deleted by the cloud function. i.e ```/document_indextrigger/{documentId}``` that way it doesn't have any conflicts. (Although I still feel like the cloud functions should have some sort of built in debouncer)

Comment: That was trivial, added `/document_index/{documentId}` to be the write trigger. The debounce happens on the client. I can edit your answer with the code if it will help @doug-stevenson